# How to match two same words from foreach loops

Tags: php

I have to store some data in data base.

```
Database Table: 
[id] - [name]     - [detail]
[1 ] - [site_url] - [http://localhost.com]
[2 ] - [home_url] = [http://localhost.com]
```

I am using this code for preview.

```
$options = get_data($conn);
  if(!empty($options)){
      foreach ($options as $Option) {
        $id = $Option['option_id'];
        $name = $Option['option_name'];
        $detial = $Option['option_detail'];
          // here i want to match option detail if site_url or home_url is same 
          // so include('homepage.php');
          else
          header('location: '.$detail) // go to home_url
      }
      }
```

I already tried this code in foreach loop after $detial = $Option['option_detail'];

```
if($name == 'site_url'){
 $site_url = $detail;
}
if($name == 'home_url'){
 $home_url = $detail;
}
if($site_url == $home_url){
  include('home.php'){
  exit();
  }else{
  header('location: '.$home_url);
  exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your `get_data` function?

Comment: I have full URL in detail column like `'http://localhost/projectname/'`

Comment: `function get_data($conn) {
    $options = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM options ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $options[] = array(
                        'option_id' => $row['id'],
   'option_name' => $row['name'],
   'option_detail' => $row['detail'],
             );
  }
 }

    return $options;
}`

Comment: you have a typo -  '$detial' - i and a are the wrong way around.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to include `home.php` when `$home_url == $site_url`. Well the problem would be here, that you assign `$detail`to `$site_url` when `$name == 'site_url'` and  `$detail`to `$home_url ` when `$name == 'home_url'`. So you want something like `$name == 'home_url' && $name == 'site_url'`, which is not possible in one iteration...